# How to get data from table A based on table B data

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

i have two tables A and B

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

I want to get all songs data which is matched to `genre_id=1` from Table A, is there any query for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select name
from A
inner join B on A.song_id=B.song_id
where B.genre_id=1
```